# Simulate Keyboard Keys on Windows not working

Tags: python, autohotkey, ctypes

I am trying to hold the keyboard keys on windows using python. I could simulate but could not hold the keys. I tried ctypes, AHK, Sendkeys but none of them worked. Is there any way to press and hold the keyboard keys until a release call. Any hint is appreciated.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From the AHK documentation: Send, {Rwin down}
Holds the right Windows key down until {RWin Up} is sent. Down/up can be combined with any key.

Comment: I tried with AHK but it does not press and hold the key. It just presses key once.